# Error while fetching team's member in ms teams

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I am trying to fetch all members of a team into msteams.
I am using this URL with postman to get all member list

```
**https://smba.trafficmanager.net/apac-client-ss.msg/v3/conversations/19:xx31xx197xxx460xxxcec76xx3axxxc9@thread.skype/members**
```

but I am getting this error into postman

```
{
    "message": "Authorization has been denied for this request."
}
```

is it right way to fetch members of a team?

Do I need to login to get this information?

is it related to any permission which I need to add into my application if I want to use this into my bot ?
Thanks

Comment: Here (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bots-context#fetching-the-team-roster) is the document to get Team member details. We can call this method and we are able to see team member details.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use this information from your bot code, I would highly recommend to use the dedicated packages:

> These Microsoft Teams–specific bot APIs are best accessed through our
>   extensions for the Bot Builder SDK. For **C#/.NET**, download our
>   **Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Teams NuGet package**. For **Node.js** development,
>   you can install the **botbuilder-teams npm package**.

By using these packages you can directly call `GetTeamsConversationMembersAsync` in C# for example

Answer (score 1):

That's the correct URL format to get the members, but note that:

1. You have to include an Authorization header with your bot's access token, e.g. "Authorization: Bearer "
2. Your bot has to be a member of the team or chat to be able to get the roster.